# Need some modification of Regular Expression in tcl

Tags: regex, tcl

i have written a regular expression as :- `if [regexp {.*DisplayName: \"([0-9]+)\"} $line match print]`
which selects all the word which contains - 0-9 digits in it , in the same code i want this expression to cath the alphabets also .

can someone please provide the code for doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `A-Za-z` inside that character class to match digits as well as alphabets.

```
if [regexp {.*DisplayName: \"([0-9A-Za-z]+)\"}
```

Comment: if [regexp {.*DisplayName: \"([0-9A-Za-z]+)\"} this A-Za-z without any space?

Comment: You might use `\w` instead of `[0-9A-Za-z]`; though it's slightly different, it tends to match what people really want when they use that set.

Comment: `\w` also matches `_`

Comment: Hi Avinash,  i didn't got you can you please give the exact expression for it

Comment: This is the exact expression. Is this fails for you?

Comment: @AvinashRaj Indeed it does, and almost always when you match `[0-9A-Za-z]`, you want (or at least can tolerate) `_` in there too.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use POSIX classes:

```
{DisplayName: \"([[:digit:][:alpha:]]+)\"}
```

See [demo](https://ideone.com/JeuW0N)

See [docs](http://www.tcl.tk/doc/howto/regexp81.tml):

> The advantage of character classes (like `[:alpha:]`) over explicit ranges in brackets (like `[a-z]`) is that character classes include characters that aren't easy to type on ASCII keyboards. For example, the Spanish language includes the character `ñ`. It doesn't fall into the range `[a-z]`, but it is in the Tcl 8.1 character class `[:alpha:]`.

Or, there is even a better solution for you: `alnum` class that includes both digits and letters:

```
{DisplayName: \"([[:alnum:]]+)\"}
```

Comment: @GauravKumar: Please check this approach. I'd also like to note that you have not accepted none of the answers to your questions. Please do not forget to accept answers that work for you.

Comment: @GauravKumar: And since you now have 15 rep points, you can also upvote answers that proved helpful to you.

Comment: @GauravKumar: Is that what you need? Or do you need more assistance with it?